# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Tags: laravel

I make a new project with laravel5.4. It is working fine on Homestead,but on VPS,I got syntax error,

> unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'
>   Diffrents:
>   Homestead php7.0
>   VPS php5.6

Comment: If the error gives you the location and line number of the problem can you add the code line (around the lines around it) to the question? But, without seeing it, it seems likely that the line in question is either using some that is new to PHP 7 or a module will be missing.

Comment: Maybe，It is time update php5 into php7，haha Thank you，guy

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it so that the question becomes closed. Cleaning up the mess :)

Comment: @NightProgrammer Please don’t edit questions that are not salvageable. And when you do edit, please try to make the question better. Your edit left a number of major grammar and syntax errors unchanged, and you actually introduced a new formatting error.

Answer (score 0):

@ Mark Walet,Thank you reminded me.I update my production environment to php7 follow "https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation", now work well.Althrough Laravel5.4 require php5.6. But it do work well in php7.Haha!